# SwiftUI - Sidebar Sizing on macOS

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

There seem to be two sidebar scales used across macOS: "compact" (see Finder, Safari) and "large" (see App Store, Reminders). The large version uses a larger font, bigger icons and has more padding between items.

Implementing a sidebar in SwiftUI always produces the "compact" version by default:

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Label("Item 1", systemImage: "1.circle.fill")
                Label("Item 2", systemImage: "2.circle.fill")
                Label("Item 3", systemImage: "3.circle.fill")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there an official way to get the more spacious version of the sidebar?

Comment: Try using the [`List.listStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/liststyle(_:)) modifier, and playing around with the various list styles https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/liststyle

Comment: @Alexander not quite what we’re looking for - the applied list style is already `sidebar` in this case (and must remain that way).